# Add a interactable navigation button on top of jqchart

Tags: jquery-ui, jqchart

Can someone let me know how to add a navigator button on top of jqChart so that when I click on that button it helps me to navigate to other page or javascript method.

[image]

Comment: Hi All, Got the solution to the above mentioned problem. I'm doing that from the javascript part. Below is the code: JS CODE: generateChart()//generates jqchart first then $("#divId").after($('<a id="arrow" href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w"></a>'));  CSS Code: .ui-icon {position:absolute;right:5%;top:5%;} This works fine. :)